# Why properties defined in `applicationContext.xml` for specific bean class do not set?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I have a simple called `HelloWorld` spring project and try to load two property from `applicationContext.xml` file, but properties do not set in their corresponding setters.

**Pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**main method:**

```
public class MyApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new 
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    TrackCoach trackCoach = context.getBean("myCoach", TrackCoach.class);
    trackCoach.getDailyWorkout();
    System.out.println(trackCoach.getName());
    System.out.println(trackCoach.getFamily());
    }
}
```

**TrackCoach.java**

```
public class TrackCoach {
private String name;
private String family;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    System.out.println("name is set");
    this.name = name;
}

public String getFamily() {
    return family;
}

public void setFamily(String family) {
    System.out.println("family is set");
    this.family = family;
}

public void getDailyWorkout() {
    System.out.println("track coach!");
    }
}
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="myCoach" class="TrackCoach">
        <property name="name" value="Jhon"/>
        <property name="family" value="Goo"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The output is:

`track coach!
null
null`

Comment: is there any errors?  Have you tried specifying the FQCN in the `ApplicationContext.xml`?  Also is the file name `ApplicationContext.xml` or `applicationContext.xml` ?

Comment: No there is no any error. I see the output. The name `applicationContext.xml` is also correct, I checked it by changing its name to `aaplicationContext.xml` and then I received an error.

Comment: Then specify `TrackCoach` as a FQCN e.g. `com.patzu.TrackCoach`

Comment: `TrackCoach` is in the root folder, I don't have package. This is path for this class `C:\Users\patzu\Desktop\JavaProjects\SpringTest\src\main\java\TrackCoach.java`

Comment: Usually a class without a package can not be loaded from another class

Comment: I also created a package 'beans' and copied all the java class to it, and this time gave the classes 'beans.TrackCoach' path again nothing changed.

Comment: Also change to use the single parameter `getBean` method `TrackCoach trackCoach = (TrackCoach) context.getBean("myCoach");`

Answer (score 0):

Full class name should be given while defining bean for example class TrackCoach is present in package com.test then it would be like **com.test.TrackCoach**

```
<bean id="myCoach" class="com.test.TrackCoach">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues that I see in your applicationContext.xml file:

1. The pom.xml which you have posted have same dependency declared twice. To run spring basic example you will need `spring-core` jar along with `spring-context` jar.
2. Define spring-context namespace. You can point to specific version of xsd if you want. Though as of now your are not using any context related tags, you will need it for most spring basic cases.

   ```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
   ```
3. You should use fully qualified class name to identify the class. Use package to group your classes.

   ```
     <bean id="myCoach" class="com.beans.TrackCoach">
        <property name="name" value="Jhon"/>
        <property name="family" value="Goo"/>
    </bean>
   ```